# How to get value from hidden field then it changed, without button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

How can I retrieve a value from HTML hidden field then its value is changed (all time value ischanged by other javascript), without a button. Every time the value changes (value is changed without page refresh), I want to grab it with javascript/ajax/JQuery without any button press.

**UPDATE**

How I change the hidden fields

```
<?php
                            echo '<select name="d2" onchange="checkTextbox12(this)">';
                            for($i=0; $i<=$d2; $i++){
                                echo 
                                 '<option value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';

                            }
                            echo '</select>';
                            ?>
                        </td>
                        <td id="kiek250decaffeinatoTest">
                            <script>
                                function checkTextbox12(element){
                                var kiek = element.value * 14;
                                document.getElementById('kiek250decaffeinatoTest').innerHTML = kiek + " LT";
                                document.getElementById('kiek250decaffeinatoKaina').value = kiek;
                                kiekis(kiek);
                            }
                            </script>

                        </td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="kiek250decaffeinatoKaina" onchange="" id="kiek250decaffeinatoKaina"  >
```

Comment: Do you mean "when" instead of "then"?

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you would need to wire-up a change event to your hidden field.

```
$(function() {
    $("#hiddenfield").change(function() {
         alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: @PatrickEvans, very true. However, there wasn't much to go on based on the question.

Comment: Either way this is still a not working answer, as hidden fields do not trigger change events.

Comment: So where is no wy to do that?

Comment: @piotr How exactly are you changing the hidden field? Can you show that code?

Answer (score 0):

Use a javascript onChange function:

```
<input type="text" onchange="myFunction()">
```

Put this in your html and link to whatever javascript function you want to execute.

Comment: hidden field not a text field, still would not work if value changed by js, http://jsfiddle.net/yDhRR/1/

Comment: true, but as the above question says, it was all I could come up with the information given in the dodgy question!

Comment: Yeas it is changed by js, and it is very hard find the solution

Answer (score 0):

Since hidden fields do not trigger change events when their values are changed by javascript you will have to manually fire the event after your code has changed the hidden fields value.

```
<input type="hidden" id="myhiddenfield" value="0" />
```

then in javascript

```
$("#myhiddenfield").change(function(){
   alert("field changed");
});

function changeField(){
   $("#myhiddenfield").val(55);
   //Manually trigger the change event.
   $("#myhiddenfield").change();
}

changeField();
```

[JSfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yDhRR/3/)

If you the code changing the field is not your code (like changed from some library) you will have to setup a timer(`setTimeout`,`setInterval` etc) to constantly watch the field for changes.